# How to get totalResults from the youtube response?

Tags: polymer, youtube-data-api

It is a very big question, but 
Here is my HTML

```
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

    <polymer-element name="test-element" attributes="q">
        <template>
            <core-ajax auto url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
                params='{"part":"snippet", "q":"{{qry}}", "maxResults":"{{vidMaxResults}}", 
"key":"{{key}}"}' handleAs="json" response="{{response}}" method='GET'></core-ajax>
            <template repeat="{{item in response.items}}">
                <div>
                <p>{{item.snippet.title}}</p>
                </div>
            </template>
            <template bind>
                <span>Total results: {{item.totalResults}}</span>
            </template>
        </template>

        <script>
        Polymer({
            response: null,
            vidMaxResults: 10,
            qry: 'Hello',
            key: ''
        });
        </script>
    </polymer-element>
```

How do i get the totalResults from the json response??

How do i get manage all the data if maxResults is not given as parameter (like thousands of results, but i would like to view only 10 at a time)?

**Also how do i get a link of the video itself for every video results (not the youtube link)??**

I am new to using these polymer and youtube api so please give me some basic idea too.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from a [`youtube.search.list()` call](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&q=test&_h=1&) looks like:

```
{
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000
  },
  "items": [{...}, {...}]
}
```

(with some fields cut for brevity).

You can access the total results value as `response.pageInfo.totalResults`.

There are no links to the raw video bytes exposed in the YouTube Data API responses. You should use the video ids to either link to the YouTube player pages or use something like [`<google-youtube>`](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-youtube) to embed the player on your page.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot about the "pageInfo" actually. Also i will look into <google-youtube> too. I would have been much happier if you had known about the raw video URLs too. But thanks anyway.